# Does Node's crypto decipher always throw an error if the password is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

I'm creating a little game-like feature for fun (so no need to be super secure).

On the server, I encrypt using a secret password:

```
const key = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'secret')
let encryption = key.update('cheerio', 'utf8', 'hex')
encryption += key.final('hex')
```

On the client, I want the user to guess the password (which is `secret` in this example), like this:

```
try {
    const key = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', guess)
    let decryption = key.update(encryption, 'hex', 'utf8')
    decryption += key.final('utf8')
 }
catch(err) {
    console.log("err", err)
 }
```

The question is, will this *always* throw an error if the `guess` fails, or do I need to compare it to my phrase (`'cheerio'`)? (I am yet to guess something that doesn't throw an error.)

I feel the former would give an extra layer of security, because then there's both a secret password AND secret word, while if I do a compare on the client the secret word is exposed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an error is not always generated when `guess` fails.

The reason for the error (*error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt*), is a wrong padding during decryption, [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DecryptFinal_ex.html). The `crypto` module uses PKCS7 padding by default. In this padding variant each padding byte has the value that corresponds to the number of padding bytes, e.g. *01*, *0202*, *030303*, *04040404* etc., see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) for details. Decryption with an incorrect password will result in random/corrupted plaintext. Its end will generally not correspond to a valid PKCS7 padding, which causes the error. However, by chance a plaintext may result, whose end matches a valid PKCS7 padding. In this case, no error is raised. E.g. a *01* byte terminating the plaintext would be compatible with PKCS7 padding, which occurs for a random password with a probability of 1/256. The same applies to *0202* with a probability of 1/65536, and so on.

This can be easily verified if padding is disabled during decryption (`key.setAutoPadding(false)`). Then no error is raised. The same applies when using a stream cipher mode (e.g., CTR) where padding is implicitly disabled.

This means that even in cases where no error is produced, a comparison with the plain text is necessary.

Note that [`createCipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) (deprecated, by the way) derives a key and an IV from the password. The same password (and thus the same key and IV) will generate the same ciphertext for the same plaintext. Therefore, a comparison of the ciphertexts serves the same purpose as a comparison of the plaintexts.

One more thing, the results of `update` and `final` must be concatenated, otherwise the result is generally not complete, i.e. in `encryption = key.final('hex')` the `=` must be replaced by `+=`, although this is probably just a typo. The same applies to decryption.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's deprecated but I could not get `createCipheriv` to work. It was VERY fuzzy with what "passwords" and such it required, while I require a plaintext password of any length. I'm sure there are ways to transform the string into whatever number of exact bytes and buffers and whatnot, but I hurt my brain trying to make it work.